# CakePHP does not work on shared hosting (Godaddy)

Tags: cakephp, shared-hosting

I tried using an internal rewrite, but only the main page shows. Any access to, for example, `http://www.example.com/logins/` will just return a 404 Not Found error.

How can I enable the mod_rewrite in a shared hosting environment (Godaddy in my case)?

Comment: Have you asked GoDaddy to enable `mod_rewrite` for you?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, even if you fix that problem you're likely to run into others due to overzealous (and probably misguided) security lockdowns on PHP.

Specifically, I currently can't get it working because the following PHP methods have "been disabled for security reasons:"

- `ini_get()`
- `fopen()`
- `readdir()`

Comment: i don't understand why they would have an article on the Bakery about how to use .htaccess on Cake+Godaddy...if it's somehow impossible to run Cake due to PHP restrictions as you mentioned?